# SQL Update 1 table with data from two others

Tags: sql, sql-update, dml

Okay I have 3 tables. The first one is the building table.

```
buildingid | buildingcode  | buildingname | level | building_hp | upkeep |
88        |    bdg ojy     |  orbital js  |    3  |    1800     |  48000 |
89        |    bdg ojy     |  orbital js  |    4  |    2100     |  56000 |
90        |    bdg ojy     |  orbital js  |    5  |    2400     |  64000 |
```

The second is the buildingsprime table.

```
id | planetcode |buildingcode| buildingname | level | buildingid | planetname
1  |    p1      |   bdg ojy  |   orbital js |   3   |    88      |   Tikinov
```

Third is the planetsprime table which was populated with data from the other two tables.

```
buildingid | planetname | buildingname | level | building _hp | upkeep
  88       |  Tikinov   |  orbital js  |  3    |  1800        |  48000
```

So what I need to do is be able to change Levels on the buildingsprime table and have it update the buildingid in the buildingsprime table and planetsprime table using the buildingid that corresponds with the level in the building table. Once that is done the planetsprime table columns data us updated according to the level stats from the buildings and buildingsprime tables. Example: If we change the level in the buildingprime table from 3 to 4 then the buildingid of 88 will update to an 89. planetprime would also update the level and buildingid as well as building_hp and upkeep to that corresponding with 89 in the buildings table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you're duplicating data. Do you really need to do that?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: This is a bad design.  Relational databases are relational.  If you make a change in one table that is RELATED to another table then no change is needed, when you need to use that data you join to the table that has the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Do these work?

```
update buildingsprime
set buildingid = (
    select b.buildingid
    from building b
    where b.buildingcode = buildingsprime.buildingcode and b.level = buildingsprime.level
)
where id = ?

update planetsprime
set building_hp = (
    select b.building_hp
    from buildingsprime bp inner join bulidings b on b.buildingid = bp.buildingid
    where bp.buildingid = planetsprime.buildingid
)
where id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use an trigger ("instead of" or a "after" )on the "buildingsprime" when you update the Level Column value to update the the "buildingID" in the buildingsprime  and update the "planetsprime" table

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_buildingsprime on buildingsprime
instead of update 
as
begin

declare @level int,
        @oldlevel int,
        @buildind_hp int,
        @buildingid int
--select current level id
select @level= level from inserted
--select the level id being updated
select @oldlevel = level from deleted

-- select the building_hp and buildingid for the new level
select @building_hp = b.building_hp, @buildingid = b.buildingid from building b 
where b.level = @level

--update building prime to set the update building id for the new level
update buildingsprime set level = @level, @building_hp =@building_hp

--update the planetsprime table with new level details where the level id = old level
update planetsprime level = @level, @building_hp =@building_hp, buildingid = @buildingid 
where level= @oldlevel

end
```

Hope this helps